# Ajax downloaded Javascript not executing in grails

Tags: html, ajax, grails, groovy

I have a layout which loads all my common resources used throughout my app but when I load a page via ajax the gsp itself renders and I can see that the ajax call downloads the js file (via firebug) but the actual code does not get executed.

I have tried the following ways to download and execute the js file from the ajax loaded page with no success. Any help will be appreciated.

Approach used

```
<r:require modules="announcements" />
<r:layoutResources/>
```

Result: js file downloaded but not executed

Approach used

```
<g:javascript library="announcements"/>

  with and without

  <r:layoutResources/>
```

Result: File not downloaded

Approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/announcements.js"></script>
```

Result: http code 302 temporary move and attempt to download of js/static/announcements.js
which gives a http code 200 but firebug shows that it is still waiting for the file and thus it's not executed.

layout.gsp:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
      <g:if test="${session.isLoggedIn}">
        <r:require modules="ui, jqueryDateFormat, loggedin" />
      </g:if>
      <g:else>
        <r:require modules="ui" />
      </g:else>
      <r:layoutResources/>

      <g:layoutHead />
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

ajax loaded page

```
<html>
  <head>
    <all methods mentioned above>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:  I resolved the issue. Turns out there was a syntax error in my JS file. Firebug did not identify error, it just stopped because the JS crashed. Had to move the library call to my layout to find the error. Fixed the JS and moved added the  line back to the gsp and all worked again.

Comment: what happens if you use <script type="text/javascript" src="js/static/announcements.js"></script>

Comment: The file loads correctly but does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most correct method.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/announcements.js"></script>
```

You should check your webserver configuration if 302 produce 200 but file isn't downloaded

Comment: where exactly would the appropriate setting be? I am running the server off Netbeans IDE.

Comment: publish somewhere outside and gimme the URL. I'll check it out

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to external servers.